# What does this name mean in Chinese?

Tags: names

What does this name mean in Chinese? I am not Chinese-born but I never really knew what it meant.

Sheng Jicheng

Comment: No idea unless additional context given. Actually I can't even guess the corresponding Chinese characters.

Comment: there is only one surname with pinyin Sheng in http://www.mandarinhouse.com/100-common-chinese-family-names :   盛           Shèng

Comment: There is no Jicheng in various lists of male given names) 小马词典 has ３ jicheng：继承 (inherit; carry on; succeed 继乘人 heir)（is even in IME editor, might be first possibility that comes to mind to Chinese listener) 蓟城 (old for Beijing)集成 integrated (as in integrated circuit). BKRS in addition has: 几成 (doubtful candidate) 寄呈,积成,稽程,继成,计程,讥称,赍呈,集成 (these are all verbs)既成 (given names usually do not belong to the general vocabulary)

Comment: @user6065 actually you might be wrong. There're 4000 surnames (22,000 if you consider the ancient China) in Chinese so I am not surprised if it comes out to be声/圣/升/生/乘. But盛is the most possible one.

Comment: @user6065 The Chinese given name is nearly impossible to be found in a dictionary.

Comment: I heard someone named '计成', it is a possibly option, of course, I just guess, no proven solutions.

Answer (score 2):

It depends based on which characters correspond to those pinyin.

Answer (score -2):

生即成 (sheng-ji-cheng)- born near success

note: this is one of many possibilities. There are many characters associated with the pinyin 'sheng', 'ji', and 'cheng'.